# Why does this program not run asynchronously?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have code that I want to run asynchronously. I expect the output to be one of the following:

```
Getting forecast 1
Getting forecast 2
Forecast 2 retrieved
Forecast 1 retrieved
```

Or

```
Getting forecast 1
Getting forecast 2
Forecast 1 retrieved
Forecast 2 retrieved
```

However, it seems that it runs synchronously because every time I run it I get

```
Getting forecast 1
Getting forecast 2
Forecast 1 retrieved
Forecast 2 retrieved
```

Code is attached below:

```
import asyncio
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

async def get_forecast1():
    print('Getting forecast 1')
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(0 , 10))
    return pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((2,2)))

async def retrieve_forecast1():

    forecast1 = await get_forecast1()
    print('Forecast 1 retrieved')
    return forecast1

async def get_forecast2():
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(0 , 10))
    return pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3,3)))

async def retrieve_forecast2():
    print('Getting forecast 2')
    forecast2 = await get_forecast2()
    print('Forecast 2 retrieved')
    return forecast2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(retrieve_forecast1(), retrieve_forecast2()))
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears I was very unlucky when running this. I ran it about 10 times and received the same output which made me believe that it was running synchronously. Upon running it a few more times, I finally received the second output.

Comment: You could test this by changing the sleep durations so `get_forecast1()` always sleeps longer than `get_forecast2()`.